# Create a branch in a project with its parent under a different project in TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, project, parent

I have the following structure:

**$/ProjectA**   [Uses MS Agile Template] 
 
      --Branch1

**$/ProjectB**   [Uses Custom Agile Template] 
 
      --[To Be Created Branch]

How can I create this new branch in ProjectB that has a parent relation with $/ProjectA/**Branch1**?

Our requirement says that we cannot be under the same Project because we must use different templates, but we still want to merge the code from new project back to the ProjectA. I checked the option in TFS when you create a new Project that lets you use an existing source control, but problem with that is:

1.There is NO option to bring in specific branches in a Project [Its all or none]

2.I cannot rename that new branch in the new project for some reason

I understand this can be achieved by using a Baseless merge between these 2 projects but I would like to know if there is still a way to have a smooth merge between these 2 branches in different projects.

P.S: we are using VS 2010 with TFS 2010

Answer (score 2):

There's shouldn't be any problems in just branching from one team project into another.  You should be able to do this just like you would any branch:  just select `$/ProjectA/Branch1`, select Branch, and enter a branch target path of `$/ProjectB/ToBeCreatedBranch`.

This is because realistically, Team Projects are of fairly limited scope in TFS version control - it primarily treats the source control tree as a big hierarchy beginning at `$/`, and team projects are not particularly special, except for some very specialized operations.  (Check-in policies are queried for by Team Project, as are settings for locklevels and labels are scoped to Team Projects.)

I'm a little unclear what version control options you specified when you created the new Team Project - you should have just created a new source tree node for it and then you can create your project branches beneath `$/ProjectB`.

Comment: Duh!, I feel like an idiot now, did not realize that you can even change the Projects when you branch. Thanks for the quick response. Ofcourse I can now even rename the new branch in $/ProjectB.

Comment: It's not obvious - some parts of TFS (work items, for example) are very much specific to the Team Project they're in and can't necessarily be easily moved around.  It's just fortunate that Version Control is not so constrained!